# manage.py syncdb is using another project's db in the virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache

I have 2 sites, in the same virtual env, in 2 different apache VirtualHosts.

When I run `python manage.py syncdb`, it says:

```
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

When I run `python manage.py inspectdb > somefile.txt`, details of the other site appear in `somefile.txt`.

So `python manage.py` is calling the file `/var/www/venv/proj1/manage.py` even when I'm sitting in the directory of: ``/var/www/venv/proj2/`. Any reason what would cause this or how to diagnose this?

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj1.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And this is how I checked $PYTHONPATH:

```
# $PYTHONPATH
-bash: /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj1:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj2:: No such file or directory
```

And this is `.bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH


PYTHONPATH=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj2:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj1:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="proj2.settings" #possibly the issue?
```

Comment: Could you show what is inside this `manage.py`? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe added to above

Comment: By the way, I remember having a lot of weird problems when two apache virtual hosts were using the same python environment - mostly C-based modules started to fail in quite insane ways..

Comment: What is the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set to?

Comment: @AndreiAvram added to the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `PYTHONPATH` has `proj1` listed before `proj2`. In that case, python will first look into `proj1` for `manage.py` and execute that, and skip the `manage.py` in the current directory, even if it exists.

As a quick fix, add the current directory to the `PYTHONPATH` like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj2
PYTHONPATH=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/proj1:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

This will first check for the script you're looking for in the current directory.

Also, unless you have a specific goal in mind, you can lose the project specific paths and always start `manage.py` from the relevant directory.